# Where to store css style sheet for sbt ScalaFX project

Tags: css, javafx, directory, sbt, scalafx

Does anyone know where in an sbt directory structure ScalaFX looks for CSS style sheets? I've tried putting them in the same directory as my ScalaFX app main file, in a resources directory, directly in src, and pretty much everywhere else - yet every time I get a message saying `Resource "whatever path I'm using/style.css" not found`.

Comment: The CSS files are loaded at runtime, so the rules are going to be exactly the same as for Java. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SBT project you put CSS stylesheets in `src/main/resources`

You can see an example project using CSS here https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx-ensemble

Assuming that your stylesheet is in `src/main/resources/path/my.css` you can load it like this

```scala
scene = new Scene {
  stylesheets += this.getClass.getResource("/path/my.css").toExternalForm
  ...
}
```